# "Peek" at buffer previously put in yypush_buffer_state?

Tags: stack, flex-lexer

I get that a `flex` buffer stack, or a stack in general, likes to abide by LIFO (Last In? First Out!). And I see in the manual that there are two "intended" ways to go about buffer selection: manually allocate and choose and free, or abide by the LIFO behavior of `yypush_buffer_state()` and `yypop_buffer_state()`.

But my reentrant lexer would do well to `yylex` its stacks in this order:

```
[3] pushed from [2] pushed from [1] pushed from [0]
[2]
[1]
[0]
[3] the same one from before...
[2]
[1]
[0]
[3]
[2]
[1]
[0]
(pop pop pop)
[0] which was [3] a moment ago.
```

I thought I would be cheeky and simply `yy_switch_to_buffer()` a lower buffer in the stack, and make use of the existing push function for automatic allocation. But it turns out that function internally refers to `YY_CURRENT_BUFFER` macro which, when a stack exists, is:

```
((struct yyguts_t*)yyscanner)->yy_buffer_stack[
((struct yyguts_t*)yyscanner)->yy_buffer_stack_top]
```

And it will become confused when we try to switch to buffers lower on the stack than the top. I guess it was a very strongly worded "intended"!

I have found that decrementing `yy_buffer_stack_top` and then doing `yy_switch_to_buffer(((struct yyguts_t*)yyscanner)->yy_buffer_stack[((struct yyguts_t*)yyscanner)->yy_buffer_stack_top], yyscanner)` seems to work. (I'd use `YY_CURRENT_BUFFER` but it actually requires an internal `yyg` definition.) I can even increment the stack top back to its maximum value and return to the untouched buffer that was only unacknowledged for a while.

Is this a poor way to go about it? Am I going to run into any problems other than: I must not `yypush_buffer_state()` or `yypop_buffer_state()` without first resetting `yy_buffer_stack_top`? I can manage that...

Comment: It would help if you were more clear about your actual goal. If you want to read your input several times, there are better ways of doing it.

Comment: I think you color your reply from readings of my other questions. Which is fine and friendly, but I don't hope for such breadcrumbs to be needed. When I find questions nobody has asked, but that might be asked, I hope to have them answered for posterity, and so they should be useful at face value. Might I even answer my questions myself? Forgive me as I learn the etiquette.

Comment: So, no, it's not that I want to "read an input several times". I have buffer Z which creates buffers A, B, C, and then they must be scanned in order Z A B C A B C A B C ... at popping completion Z again until more buffer pushes are warranted. And A, B, C read by characters, not by whole lines like Z, and they are all different. In the end, what I am writing is a notation for music, and my solution seems to work, unless a problem arises.

Comment: What's not clear to me here is whether you mean that you want to read all of A, then all of B, then all of C, and then read all of A again, etc., or whether there is some trigger in A which causes reading to switch to B, and then something in B which cause a switch to C, and then a switch back to where you left off in A, etc. I'm not sure that even that way of putting it is clear; concrete examples are almost always easier to follow. Also, is the fact that there are three of these a given? Or could Z at some point generate D as well?

Comment: By the way, it is perfectly acceptable to answer your own questions. This is addressed in the site help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Oh, I see what was unclear. No, my YY_BREAK macro is redefined to ensure every action has at least a fallback return statement (I hope I say that right). So it will scan character by character and not repeat. And no, not 3: I am hoping for Z to discover arbitrarily many lines to scroll through before deciding to doing that. This made it more comfortable to use Flex's certified sort of stack utility.

Comment: So you're basically trying to transpose ABC by reading vertically first and then horizontally? I.e. you have three buffers which will produce the token sequences A1 A2 A3 A4... An;  B1 B2 B3 ... Bn; and C1 C2 C3 ... Cn, but you actually want to produce the token sequence A1 B1 C1 A2 B2 C2 A3 B3 C3 ... An Bn Cn?

Comment: Yes, though there's less variety, it's really just tokens A B C A B C. Or if you want the actuality it's RH(ythm) PI(tch) VE(locity) aka loudness...

Comment: Umm, so how could there be four of them? Do note attributes just suddenly appear? (And where are you encoding duration?)

Comment: Hey rici... Rest assured that I have a plan. If in between []rh and []pi is a []BS type line that isn't recognized, we'll just print it unchanged or ignore it entirely if we're converting to something else. I'm working to make it super easy to expand my notation anyway. When I have more to show, I'll be happy to post it. After all, it has an attribute I haven't mentioned, and I must ask if it's got a name in the vocabulary. I'll love to hear your input then, and I'm grateful for all you've done!